# Can we provide an example and motivation on when to use covariant and contravariant?

Tags: python, types, pytorch, typing, liskov-substitution-principle

I have a background in machine/deep learning but I aspire to be a good software engineer as well.

I have some troubles finding real use cases of covariant/contravariant (partly because this is a new concept for me and the initial learning curve is difficult).

I would like a concrete motivation and example on when covariant/contravariant is used, in particular, I would appreciate the example to be such that if covariant/contravariant is not applied, then the application would be buggy/not type safe.

To start, I know PyTorch's `Dataset` and `DataLoader` is parametrized by a covariant type:

```py
class Dataset(Generic[T_co]):
    r"""An abstract class representing a :class:`Dataset`.

    All datasets that represent a map from keys to data samples should subclass
    it. All subclasses should overwrite :meth:`__getitem__`, supporting fetching a
    data sample for a given key. Subclasses could also optionally overwrite
    :meth:`__len__`, which is expected to return the size of the dataset by many
    :class:`~torch.utils.data.Sampler` implementations and the default options
    of :class:`~torch.utils.data.DataLoader`. Subclasses could also
    optionally implement :meth:`__getitems__`, for speedup batched samples
    loading. This method accepts list of indices of samples of batch and returns
    list of samples.

    .. note::
      :class:`~torch.utils.data.DataLoader` by default constructs a index
      sampler that yields integral indices.  To make it work with a map-style
      dataset with non-integral indices/keys, a custom sampler must be provided.
    """

    def __getitem__(self, index) -> T_co:
        raise NotImplementedError("Subclasses of Dataset should implement __getitem__.")

    # def __getitems__(self, indices: List) -> List[T_co]:
    # Not implemented to prevent false-positives in fetcher check in
    # torch.utils.data._utils.fetch._MapDatasetFetcher

    def __add__(self, other: 'Dataset[T_co]') -> 'ConcatDataset[T_co]':
        return ConcatDataset([self, other])

    # No `def __len__(self)` default?
    # See NOTE [ Lack of Default `__len__` in Python Abstract Base Classes ]
    # in pytorch/torch/utils/data/sampler.py
```

I wonder if someone can come up with convincing example of why a `Dataset` needs to be covariant.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you want `DataSet[bool]` to be a subtype of `DataSet[int]`, because `bool` is a subtype of `int`. By default, generic types are *invariant*, because the assumption is that the type will be mutable.

Compare tuples and lists. Tuples are covariant, because you can't modify them. The only thing you can do is read *from* them, so if you need a `tuple[int]` value, a tuple of any subclass of `int` will do. Lists, on the other hand, are invariant, because you don't necessarily know if you will be reading *from* the list or writing *to* the list. (If reading `int`s, you can take a `list[bool]` in place of `list[int]`; if writing `bool`s, you can take a `list[int]` instead a `list[bool]`. But in general, neither is substitutable for the other.)

Contravariance doesn't really come up with traditional containers, but does when talking about function types. A function `f` is substitutable for a function `g` if `f` accepts *all* the same arguments (but possibly  more) that `g` does, and returns *some* of the same arguments (but possibly fewer) than `g` could. We describe this as saying that function types are *contravariant* in their argument(s) and *covariant* in their return types.